# Why does my naive Elasticsearch update fail frequently with a document version conflict?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using version 0.9 and I have this very naive approach to update documents, which essentially does a compare and swap:
(only relevant code is shown)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRY; i++) {
        GetResponse get = client.prepareGet().execute().actionGet();
        // Assume document already exists
         try {
              client
                .prepareIndex()
                .setId(id)
                .setSource(newDoc)
                .setVersion(get.getVersion())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
                // Successfully updated
         } catch (VersionConflictEngineException e) {
             continue; //retry
         }
         throw UpdateFailedException();
    }
```

The code works for most of the updates, but also fails more frequent than I'd expect with version conflict. Curiously, it always seems that the server document is +1 the expected version when it fails. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

I understand Elasticsearch has a proper update functionality but I can't use this ATM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just legitimately updating documents very frequently due to a bug.